# How can I stop WP Image Editor upscaling from looking so pixellated?

Tags: images

I know the [WP Image Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor) is not meant to upsize images, gives a WP_Error if you try, and any time you upsize an image you lose quality - but as mentioned in their source code you can use the 'image_resize_dimensions' filter to force it to scale up if a particular image application is required to be a certain size.

The problem I'm having is that any upscaling done by Imagemagick in this case is actually much worse than just zooming in the browser - Here's a really upscaled, *really pixelated* example just to show what I mean:

Browser screenshot showing zoom in on original image, not *too* bad:
[image: Browser ok image]

Result of upscale with wp image editor ->resize, looks super pixelated:
[image: Ugly upsize]

Is there a way to get WP image editor/Imagemagick to not upsize images in such a way that the pixellation is so obvious?

Comment: Use CSS to upscale via the "background-size" property. Also note WordPress has this too: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/

Comment: @NathanPowell Thanks, I know about responsive images in WP4.4 - how would that help with this? A css solution doesn't help where I'm required to have a certain WidthxHeight pixel image!

Comment: Sorry, I totally disregarded your question. To help with a solution can you explain why you are trying to upscale rather than zoom? Up scaling images in Photoshop is even a science with many variables, so I don't think doing this can solve your problem. With CSS you can force an image back size minimum height and width. The image can be auto generated in WordPress at a smaller scale if it doesn't meet the minimum criteria, then viola, you have a small image zoomed to fit your box.

Comment: @NathanPowell CSS doesn't help when image is provided to a system that requires WxH pixel image.

Comment: What is the intended resulting code? Is it a problem to change the markup where the images are rendered?